# Communicating between web server and application

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue

Normally if I want to pass data from a web server to an application server, I'd store that data in a database, and then have the application server periodically query the database to check for new data. The main problem with this is that it isn't real-time, and causes unnecessary load on the DB.

I'm sure there's many better ways of doing this, but I'm not aware of what they are.

I'm thinking of using a message broker such as RabbitMQ to handle this, but could this be too over the top as I'm not necessarily handling that much data? Is this what message brokers are meant for?

Not sure if I'm thinking about this the wrong way, any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the data to remain stored on the database? What operating system/web server/application server are you using? As general advice, a simple solution that would work in most cases would be to open a local port from the application server and have the web server connect and supply data through it. A message broker is probably a decent choice though as well if you plan to scale the functionality.

Comment: @HappyPandaFace The data would need to remain stored in the database, but I wouldn't want to monitor this as it wouldn't be real-time (will edit question).

Operating system is Ubuntu for both web and application server, web server is running LEMP, application server is Node.

Comment: Yeah, you can open a TCP socket in node (https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html). I'm more familiar with Apache than nginx... but maybe there's a way to connect to this socket from nginx. I'd use PHP in Apache. Since you want to store the data in the DB anyway, this socket could simply tell the application server to look in the db and maybe provide an ID to search for.